# omega function (Psych package R) not working with plot=TRUE

Tags: r, psych

I have to first say that I am not an R user, but I want to apply a certain function I could only find in R.

My purpose is to get a bifactor factor-analysis model using the [omega](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.8.12/topics/omega) function from the Psych package. I have a data frame with 33 columns and about 100,000 observations and when I call the function `(omega(df))`
I get the following error:

> Error in nchar(tv[1, 21]) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector

I have no idea what it means. If I follow the example in [this doc](https://personality-project.org/r/psych_for_sem.pdf) with their data (named "bifact") it works fine, but the example uses a correlation matrix, while I want to use the entire data to be able to extract the factor scores. When I try to call the function with  `omega(cor(df))`
I still get the same error.

Attached is a randomly generated data set that produces the same error.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

A clue to the solution could be the fact that with set.seed(0) I get a different error than with set.seed(100):

`set.seed(100)`
`s_df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(seq_len(10000), ncol=1), matrix(rnorm(n=6*10000, mean = 20, sd = 10), ncol=6)))[2:7]`
`omega(s_df)`

> Error in nchar(tv[1, 21]) : 'nchar()' requires a character vector

while:
`set.seed(0)`
`s_df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(seq_len(10000), ncol=1), matrix(rnorm(n=6*10000, mean = 20, sd = 10), ncol=6)))[2:7]`
`omega(s_df)`

> Error in omega.diagram(omega, main = title, sl = sl, labels = labels,  :
> object 'd.arrow' not found

EDIT: everything works when I call the function with plot=FALSE.
However, I still would like the plot to work. (plot=TRUE) throughs the unwanted error.

Comment: What happens if you just run `cor(df)`?   Do you get an error? Does the matrix contain NAs?

Comment: It runs just fine, no NAs

Comment: If you could replicate the problem with a subset of the data (and then post the data), that you could post, that would be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I've attached just a random data set that generates the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out I just didn't have the 'Rgraphviz' package installed.

After installing it everything worked great.